# How can I secure a loose shower head trim ring?

Tags: shower

I am noticing that the shower head escutcheon (right word?) or cap is starting to lift from the wall and was wondering if I should try to caulk around it or get a flat head & remove and replace it?

[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Also, please don't disparage your gender by implying that the lack of a husband is a disability.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to push the escutcheon back in place, but if it has just recently "popped out" there may be an issue behind it .

You should explore to see if there is a needed repair.
This should be done after running the shower for a bit, so if the arm is leaking there will be wetness to be found.

If you can,  pull the escutcheon out further and shine a light in the opening to examine what is there.  If nothing, ( no signs of leaks, no drywall or insulation looking wet, nothing with a bulging appearance) then push it back flush. If needed you can caulk it.

Obviously if there is an issue it should be repaired before replacing the escutcheon.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are it's just gotten loose from the forces of repeated cycling the shower on and off (maybe the pipe isn't secured quite as well as it should be behind the wall).  Next time you're in the shower, closely observe the escutcheon when you turn on the shower head.  If it moves a little, that's probably your problem.  If so, just tap it back into place and caulk it with some acrylic caulk (allow to cure before using the shower).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the wear mark on the nipple there's substantial movement in the plumbing. That's not ideal. The eared fitting into which the nipple is threaded should be rigidly mounted. It's mostly an aesthetic problem, though.

The trim ring has tabs pressed into it which fit snugly against the nipple to hold position. These may have gotten bent a bit. You could remove the shower head, pull the trim ring off, and bend the tabs inward slightly to restore tension.

Or just pick up an new one. It'll be clean and shiny and should fit snugly. You could replace the nipple as well, but that'll need some thread tape to seal properly. That's not a difficult job once you learn a few basics.

If the problem continues, apply some silicone caulk to the *nipple* behind the trim ring to secure it. Don't caulk the outside of the ring itself. That'll look bad and may result in damage to the wall.